# "Disk read error, press ctrl+alt+del" message on bootup HP NC8000

Tags: boot, laptop

I've upgraded my computer from Compaq Evo N1020V to HP NC8000 and also moved my half-year old HDD drive Samsung HM160HC to it.

I've got one partition. It was working fine for 2 days and then after turning computer off and then on I got:

"Disk read error, press ctrl+alt+del" message on bootup

I've booted from diagnostic CD and all content is still on drive, so I've copied all important files to my USB drive and then restored the whole system from VHD image. Then it's working fine for next 2 days and then it happens again. It's really annoying. My old Compaq was working for 10 years without any problems...

Disk is completely fine, SMART ok, I've also tested with BIOS HDD Test utility and no errors.

Notebook: HP NC8000, 1 GB RAM (2x512 MB), Radeon Mobility 9600 64 MB, 160 GB HDD, DVD combo
Windows XP Professional SP3 Polish 32-bit

How to fix this permanently ?

Comment: Do you now have two disks in your HP NC8000, or just one?

Comment: Just one in normal HDD bay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was related to disk size. It didn't like the 160 GB. I've installed 30 GB SSD in Multibay as a second disk and now it's all ok ;)

Comment: Problem is the boot order in the BIOS?

Comment: No. It's just looking for missing drives.

Comment: So it wont boot with the missing device then

Comment: Correct. BIOS is the latest version F.18.

Answer (score 0):

Try Samsung/Seagate's own diagnostic utilities (such as SeaTools) to thoroughly test the drive.

I would also suggest you change the HDD's PATA cable if possible and see if that fixes the issue (provided of course the drive's health checks out).

Comment: There are no disk cables inside this laptop. I'm buying second HDD and I will install 40 GB SATA SSD in MultiBay. Maybe it will work ok then.

Comment: Tried SeaTools and disk is completely fine...